# Publish APIM Developer portal through terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, wso2-api-manager, azure-api-management

Hi I have searched through docs on and can't quite find how to publish the developer portal through terraform. My terraform does spool a resource group with an API Management service resource but I want it to also publish the developer portal and enable CORS. Is this possible through terraform or has to be done manually after I have the rg spooled?

[image]

Updated terraform looking at the documentation here: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/api_management#host_name

There is a block for developer portal but I am not sure if this actually publishes it and also not sure what to put in the host_name. Please assist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can completely configure the APIM and its portal from an ARM template but you can't publish the content. There are [scripts](https://github.com/Azure/api-management-developer-portal/tree/master/scripts.v3) in the Github repo to do this using the [rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/).

Publishing content using those scripts will work for the managed portal. If you're hosting your own version of the portal you'll have to take some additional steps, [according to the migration script](https://github.com/Azure/api-management-developer-portal/blob/master/scripts.v3/migrate.js#L26).

If you can get Terraform to execute NodeJs scripts, you should be able to use these to push content to the portal and publish it.

Please also check the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/automate-portal-deployments) that were recently added about the migration script.

Answer (score 1):

I have never used terraform but I believe what you highlighted would only create a custom domain for your developer portal.

Hostname would be a custom domain, or you can use the default {apimname}.developer.azure-api.net. If you provide a custom domain for your developer portal you would have to provide a SSL certificate and also you have to have a CName for this custom domain.

I do no think the developer portal would be published `Can I deploy everything through ARM templates now? The only thing that's not available is developer portal content. Everything else is available through ARM.` [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-api-management-devops-resource-kit/blob/9f99488029e70405a69f383697e813cdee432f46/FAQ.md#can-i-deploy-everything-through-arm-templates-now)

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an APIM manually and see what settings is it using for the developer portal in [Azure Resource Explorer](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/introducing-azure-resource-explorer-for-the-azure-resource-management-apis). Try to replicate those settings in your code.